# How to publish and consume office web add-ins only internally?

Tags: office-js

We're planning to develop a series of add-ons for office, but we don't want to publish them to app store because these add-ons are only developed for our employees.

But we still want to gather our add-ons on a store.

Is it possible that we quickly build our own app store so that our employees can download add-ons conveniently? Does office has this api? I didn't find it in the document.

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your use case scenario is [Centralized Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment) via the Office 365 admin center. In this way you can publish add-ins to users, groups or an organization.